# Twilio Whatsapp API using Conversations API

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-conversations

I am testing the Twilio Whatsapp API using Conversations API and I use the Masked communication between 2 whatsapp numbers. My use case is that out of the 2 whatsapp numbers, one always has to be the same number in multiple active conversations.
How do I overcome the limitation of the (personal number + proxy address) pair being available for only 1 active conversation at a time.

Should I enable multiple whatsapp senders in this instance to be able to use multiple proxy address for the same whatsapp number at a time? Or is there any setting available to override this logic please?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated please.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your use case a bit more, please? An example of how you are using the proxy would be helpful.

Since these interactions are all one-to-one (proxy to personal) I think you could forgo the Conversations API and just use the Messaging API. Conversations are great when there are multiple parties in the chat, but can add complexity for one-to-one conversations.